# Remove "/" from regex angularjs

Tags: angularjs, regex

I am using regex to split string if find `/` in the string. My code to find string and split is :-

```
$scope.string = $scope.newStr;
$scope.tokens = $scope.string.match(/[^\/]+\/?|\//g);
console.log($scope.tokens);
```

This give me output as `["1.1.1.2/", "23"]` I don't want `/` in `1.1.1.2/`.

Also I want to display **23** separately on new model.

Comment: Try just [`/[^\/]+/g`](https://regex101.com/r/i2mSfy/1) to extract chunks of 1+ chars other than `/`. Or split with `/`.

Comment: And what is the actual input string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks it's working , but how will I bind those in two different model ? My output is now `["1.1.1.2", "23"]`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen actual input string is `$scope.newStr` whose value is  `1.1.1.2/23` .  `1.1.1.2` is for gateway and `23` would be mask

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I got it , thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.newStr = '1.1.1.2/23';
    $scope.string = $scope.newStr;
    $scope.tokens = $scope.string.split("/")
    for(let i=0; i<$scope.tokens.length; i++)
    {
       console.log($scope.tokens[i]);
    }  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks , nice solution.